# Powershell Scripting - How to use less IF / IF-ELSE statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement, syntax, logic

I mainly code with PowerShell and 85% of my scripts are built with it.

The more I go on and code, the more I realize that I always use IF statements, which to be fair are sometimes needed, but since I put a lot of checks and throws in my code I find my scripts full of these statements. What's a different logical approach that I could take?

I tried looking online and found Ternary Operators but couldn't find good documentation for PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can use the following constructs to avoid the need for [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_If) statements in simple cases:

- `?:`, the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false)

  ```bash
  # Alternative to:
  #   $foo = if ($true) { 'bar' } else { 'baz' }
  $foo = $true ? 'bar' : 'baz'
  ```
- `??`, the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-coalescing-operator-)

  ```bash
  # Alternative to:
  #   $foo = if ($null -ne $possiblyNull) { $possiblyNull } else { 'default' }
  $foo = $possiblyNull ?? 'default'
  ```
- `?.`, the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

  ```bash
  # Alternative to:
  #   if ($null -ne $possiblyNull) { $possiblyNull.ToString() } 
  ${possiblyNull}?.ToString()
  ```

  - Note the - unfortunate - need to enclose the variable name in `{...}` for `?.` to work as intended, because - surprisingly - `?` is a legal character in a PowerShell variable name.
  - [GitHub #11379](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11379) asks for this obscure requirement to be lifted, based on analysis that shows that only very little existing code, if any, would be impacted by interpreting a trailing `?` *as part of `?.`* rather than as part of the variable name. Sadly, despite claims to revisit the issue - see [GitHub issue #14025](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14025) - no action was ever taken.
  - Also note that while `.?` tests the *object itself* for being `$null`, there is currently no way to conditionally access an object's *property* that *may or may not exist*.

    - While such a feature isn't strictly necessary *by default*, because PowerShell simply returns `$null` if you access a non-existent property (e.g., `$PSCulture.NoSuchProperty`), it does matter when [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 2` or higher is in effect, in which case attempts to access a non-existent property *fail* (which the current implementation of `?.` does *not* prevent).
    - [GitHub issue #15338](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15338) proposes adding support for such *property-existence-conditional access*, ideally  by extending the semantics of `?.`

Comment: This is great, is there something like this just for the "if" statement? I've noticed the ternary conditional operator is for the "if-else" statement only (at least from what I saw).

Comment: UPDATE: I discovered that I can just do $foo = $true ? 'bar' : $null.